# sum of the numbers of both subsets are equal.

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of 10 numbers chosen from {10,11,...,99}. Prove that in this set there are two non-empty and different subsets such that the sum of the numbers of both subsets are equal.
Please for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The pigeonhole principle.

Comment: A good hint for a person who is not familiar with pigeonhole principle but usually problems like this are given just after studying it so this might be no help at all.

Comment: If more hint is needed: how many different subsets are there?  Estimate how many possible values for the sum.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it can be proven using computers that given a set of $9$ integers in the set $\{1,2\dots 100\}$ there wil always be two subsets that add up the same. You need the set to be at least $\{1,2,3\dots 161\}$ to get set of $9$ numbers where all the subsets have different sums.

On the other hand the set $ \{40,60,71,77,80,82,83,84\} $ shows there are $8$ integers where all the subsets have different sums.

[Here](http://fks.sk/~kubus/doc/201012ssd.pdf) is a good resource on the matter

As for the actual problem see the sums are all between $1$ and $1000$ and there are $1024$ subsets, conclude using the pidgeonhole principle.

Also related is problem $4$ of the $2014$ [APMO](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=1&cid=20&year=2014&sid=4d7aeb6ecb7f4259f6785d5230ad3760), this answer borrows from the comments in mathlinks on that problem